# manipulate data fetched from remote api angular 2

Tags: loops, angular, httprequest, observable

Im receiving data from the Marvel api and use ngFor to display the data.
Before displaying the data I need to make some changes to it.
If the name doesn't exist or the description is empty I want to show a message.

Where is the best place to manipulate data and how can I do this?

I tried something like this in my comic view after the subscribe but it didnt work.

```
If (stuff.data.results['0'].title == ''){
stuff.data.results['0'].title == 'try gain'}
```

my service.ts

```
  getComics(searchterm): Observable<any> {
    const search: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    search.set('titleStartsWith',searchterm);
    search.set('ts', '1'); // time stamp
    search.set('apikey', 'key');
    search.set('hash', 'key');
    let obs: Observable<any> = this.http
      .get(ComicService.BASE_URL, new RequestOptions({search}))
      .map( (res) => res.json());
      console.log("obj " + obs)
    return obs;
  }
```

my comic-view.ts

```
 searchComics(event): boolean {
    this.error = 'fout'
    this._comicService.getComics(this.searchterm)
      .subscribe(
      stuff => {
        this.stuff = stuff; console.log('title: ' + stuff.data.results['0'].title + ' description:' +
          stuff.data.results['0'].description);
      },
      error => { this.error = error;  }
      );
    return false;
  }
```

comis.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor=" let x of stuff?.data?.results ">
    <label> Title:</label> {{x.title}}
    <br>
    <label> description: </label> {{x.description}}
    <br>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I found an answer :If the name doesn't exist or the description is empty you can use {{x.description || 'there is no description'}}.

Comment: I still want to know if its possible to make changes to the data before displaying it. I think it was possible in angularjs